# Making a snaphot in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed wsl 2 in machine (Using Windows 10 pro). I downloaded the ubuntu distribution 20.04. I wonder if can make snapshots and clones of it as in Vmware.
Thank you !

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1164818/how-to-backup-wsl-linux-subsystem-for-windows-10-before-system-reset-or-reins

Answer (score 3):

@Esther's comment pointing to Super User is a good one, but I think it's a question worthy of having its own answer here on Ask Ubuntu.  It's also in need of an *updated* answer since WSL has new features in this area.

The Super User question also only covers *cloning/backups*, but not true "snapshots", which I consider to typically mean "incremental" backups.  So I'll *attempt* to touch on "snapshots" in this answer as well.

##### Backing up a WSL1 or WSL2 distribution

The supported mechanism for "backing up" a WSL1 or WSL2 distribution is to use `wsl --export`.  As with most backups, it's best to close the files in use first, so it's also best to perform these actions from PowerShell.

1. Exit Ubuntu on WSL
2. From PowerShell:

   ```
   wsl -l -v
   # Confirm your distribution name for the following commands
   wsl --terminate <distro_name>

   # Create directory structure, adjust to preference:
   mkdir "$env:userprofile\WSL\images"

   # You can hardcode the backup name below if you wish.
   # This example creates it with a date/timestamp-prefix on the tarball:

   wsl --export <distroname> "$env:userprofile\WSL\images\$(date -f yyyyMMdd_HHmmss)_Ubuntu.tar"
   ```

##### Restoring the previous backup to a new instance (creating a cloned instance)

Creating the clone can be done by with the `wsl --import` command to create a new instance from the backup made in the previous step.

Again, from PowerShell:

```
# Adjust paths and names to your preference
mkdir "$env:userprofile\WSL\instances\Ubuntu20.04_TestClone"
wsl --import Ubuntu20.04_TestClone "$env:userprofile\WSL\instances\Ubuntu20.04_TestClone" <path_to_previous_backup.tar> --version 2
```

WSL does not "remember" the default user for `--import`ed instances so you'll need to set that manually.  See [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1627461/1210833) for how to do that using a `/etc/wsl.conf` file.

##### New, shorter option for WSL2 in WSL Preview

In the latest version of WSL (currently in Preview), there are several additional options for `wsl --import` (as well as `--export`).

If you are running Windows 11 (which I know you aren't, but others may, and eventually you may), then you can install it from the Microsoft Store.  It is listed there as *"Windows Subsystem for Linux Preview"*.

With this version, you can directly import a VHDX file (the virtual disk of a WSL2 instance) from an existing instance into a new instance using `wsl --import --vhd`.  First, you'll need to know where your existing VHDX resides.

From PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ | ForEach-Object { (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH) | Select-Object DistributionName,BasePath }
```

Then simply import from that location with:

```
# Adjust paths and names to your preference
mkdir "$env:userprofile\WSL\instances\Ubuntu20.04_TestClone"
wsl --import Ubuntu20.04_TestClone "$env:userprofile\WSL\instances\Ubuntu20.04_TestClone" <path_to_main_distro>\ext4.vhdx> --vhd --version 2
```

Note, if you receive the following error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

... then try this in order:

- `wsl --terminate <distro>` the existing instance, then try the `--import` again.
- Stop Docker Desktop if it is running, then try the `--import` again.
- `wsl --shutdown`, then try the `--import` again.

There is one downside to this method, in that this is purely a "copy" of the existing WSL2 vhdx file.  That means that if it is consuming more space than needed, the new image will have the same "wasted space" (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1612289/1210833) for more info).

##### Incremental Snapshots

WSL does not yet have a feature that will do incremental snapshots to save space.  It *may* be possible to hack this together manually, but I have not tested this technique yet personally.  The idea, at a high level is:

- Create a tarball of the existing instance using Gnu `tar`'s [incremental dump](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Incremental-Dumps.html) feature.
- Specify `--one-file-system` and `--xattrs` to capture the right files in the actual filesystem (and their extended attributes, if used in your distribution).
- Reconstruct a "non-incremental" tarball from the incremental tarball.
- Restore it using `wsl --import`.

It's been something I've wanted to try for a while, but I just haven't had the time yet.